# If user passes a primitive type argument to println(), what exactly happens behind the scene?

Tags: java

If user passes a primitive type argument to `println()`, what exactly happens behind the scene? e.g.

```
int i =1;

System.out.println("My Int"+i);

//and in

System.out.println(i)
```

How does it print `"My Int 1"` and `"1"`, even though it needs a `String` object?

**updated..**

What I think is `AutoBoxing` comes into play. Is that true, too?

Comment: No, this has nothing to with autoboxing. It worked the same way already in the first versions of Java, long before autoboxing was introduced (in Java 5).

Comment: @Peter Torok, then there must be something els going on.. i thought it was because of Boxing.. i would accepted if this was an answer...

Comment: What else needs to be going on? It is just a regular method call to a method with an int parameter...

Comment: @Thilo.. i don't need anything to go on.. i just wanted to know if any one knows how its done, so that even i may understand a bit about the way its done.. nothing more or less..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not need a String object, and there is no autoboxing at play here, either. There are [methods for primitive types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28int%29) as well:

> public void print(int i)
>
> Print an integer. The string produced by String.valueOf(int) is translated into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

Comment: your answer is good as well.. if its getting translated to bytes then i don't have anything further to ask.. i will go with you..

Comment: Actually, the spec says that for string concatenation ( the `"My Int"+i` case) the JVM would do `new Integer(i)` behind the scenes and then call `toString()` which in turn results in `String.valueOf(i)` again. :)

Comment: Yes, I was only answering the part about the single int. And `new Integer()` does not happen anymore (since 1.5). It now does `Integer#valueOf`

Comment: Actually, looking at the decompilation provided by @Jigar, what really happens is `new StringBuilder().append("My Int").append(i).toString()`. So Integer class is not involved.

Answer (score 6):

[`System.out`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a [`PrintStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). `PrintStream` has plenty of overloads for `println`, suche as [`println(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28int%29) or [`println(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29), so the compiler will simply choose the most appropriate.

What happens in your first example is that you construct a new `String` using string concatenation of `"My Int"` and `i` and pass *that* `String` to the `println` method. That method needs not know how to "print concatenated `String` values", because it simply gets a normal `String` object.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println("My Int"+i);
```

equals

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("My Int").append(i).toString();
```

**For example :**

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] ar){
    int i = 10;
    System.out.println("My Int"+i);
  }
}
```

now observe the code

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   bipush  10
   2:   istore_1
   3:   getstatic       #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   6:   new     #3; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   9:   dup
   10:  invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   13:  ldc     #5; //String My Int
   15:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/
String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   18:  iload_1
   19:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lan
g/StringBuilder;
   22:  invokevirtual   #8; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/la
ng/String;
   25:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Str
ing;)V
   28:  return
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually println doesn't need only a String object. It is defined for int too.

EDIT:

how : println is an overloaded method. There are different version of it:

```
public void println(int x) {
     print(x);
```

}
    public void println(long x) {}
    ...

```
//that is what it does
public void print(int i) {
write(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Comment: how? `public void println(int i)`

Comment: @Thilo, sir i agree it has overloaded versions, i'm asking what those overloaded version do to print this int value.. i guess its AutoBoxing(java1.6)... i totally accept the answer.. but i want to know it in deep..

Comment: There is no auto boxing going on. It is just a regular method call to a method with an int parameter...

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is a [`PrintStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) which has overloaded `println` methods for all primitive types, `String` and `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

The principle is called method overloading. You can define multiple methods with the same name, as long as the parameter list is different.

```
public class YourClass() {
    public int yourMethod(Object param) {return 0};
    // allowed: other parameters
    public int yourMethod(int i) {return 1};
    // allowed: wrapper classes are different enough
    public int yourMethod(Integer i) {return 2};
    // allowed: wrapper classes are different enough
    // not allowed: same parameter list, but different return type
    public float yourMethod(int i) {return 0.5f}; /* COMPILE ERROR */
}
```

When invoking the method, the compiler chooses the best fitting method.

```
YourClass obj = new YourClass();
Integer i = 1; // auto boxing
obj.yourMethod(i);            // returns 2
obj.yourMethod(i.intValue()); // returns 1
obj.yourMethod((Object)i);    // returns 0
obj.yourMethod(0.5);          // COMPILE ERROR, there is no yourMethod(double)
```